# import and display a .txt file in wxpython

Tags: python, text, wxpython

I try to import a .txt file and display its values into a wxpython Panel.

But first I need to be able to import the data, and I am stuck at that point. As a test, I tryed :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#.*. coding: utf-8 .*.

f = open('data.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    words = line.split("-")
```

when I run it, I don't get an error but nothing is happening in the shell.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nothing is happening in the shell because you don't `print` anything.

Comment: Oh my bad... thank now it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wxPython panel widget won't display text. You will need to use a `wx.TextCtrl` for that or possibly the rich text control widget. Here's a minimal example:

```
import os
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.my_text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Open Text File')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpen)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.my_text, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onOpen(self, event):
        wildcard = "TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open Text Files", wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return

        path = dialog.GetPath()

        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path) as fobj:
                for line in fobj:
                    self.my_text.WriteText(line)


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Text File Reader')

        panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

or just post data in string form to a label

```
`import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size = size)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizerv = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Open target text file to view content's", pos=(0, 30))
        sizerv.Add(self.label)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="File")
        sizer.Add(self.btn, 10)
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnclickMe)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnclickMe(self, event):
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open TXT file", wildcard="TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt",
                           style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return 
            pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
            try:
                with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                    with open(pathname) as f:
                        text =""
                        for line in f:
                            text += line.strip()+"\n"
                        self.label.SetLabelText(text)
            except IOError:
                wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title="Button Events", size=(600, 500))
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()`
```